# Can one create a native iPhone app with HTML5 and JavaScript?

Tags: iphone

Can one create a native iPhone app with HTML5 and JavaScript?  How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use **Phone gap** for developing iphone applications.
It's a free sdk and you can develop applications for I-phone,android,windows mobile,black berry etc using this sdk. **Titanium** sdk is another one. Phone gap uses html, css, javascript and jquery for application development.

But you need to create an IPA on XCode for installing it on Apple devices (Iphone,Ipad etc).
Please check these sdk links: [Phone gap](http://phonegap.com/),[Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Comment: Matt is right, also there is a lot of limitations when implementing the UIElements and functionality.